# How to show results from a Biopython Pubmed search in a Gtk.TextView?

Tags: python, gtk, biopython, pubmed

I want to search Pubmed using Biopython (the code is in the Biopython documentation) and display the results (title, authors, source) of each record in a Gtk.TextView. The code works when just printed but when I try to use the TextView, only the first record is shown. If anyone knows why this is the case, I'd appreciate the help.

Here is what I've got so far...

```
def pbmd_search(self): #searches pubmed database, using Biopython documentation
    handle = Entrez.egquery(term=self.entry.get_text())
    record = Entrez.read(handle)
    for row in record["eGQueryResult"]:
        if row["DbName"]=="pubmed":
            print(row["Count"])

    handle = Entrez.esearch(db="pubmed", term=self.entry.get_text(), retmax=1000)
    record = Entrez.read(handle)
    idlist = record["IdList"]

    handle = Entrez.efetch(db="pubmed", id=idlist, rettype="medline", retmode="text")
    records = Medline.parse(handle)
    records = list(records)

    records_str = ""
    tv = Gtk.TextView()
    for record in records:
        records_str +=("title:", record.get("TI", "?"), "authors:", record.get("AU", "?"), "source:", record.get("SO", "?"), (""))
        #print(records_str)

    tv.get_buffer().set_text(str(records_str))
    tv.set_editable(False)          
    sw = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
    sw.set_size_request(300,200)
    sw.add(tv)
    w = Gtk.Window()                                                                                                                                                        w.add(sw)
    w.show_all()
```

Comment: This is not a self-contained example which makes it hard to reproduce your problem. Your (outcommented) `print` statement is within the `for` loop, so if you use it you will first see the first entry, then the first and second entry and so on?

Comment: Sorry for the non-reproducibility. Yes the outcommented print statement does work, however I don't want to print the result, I want to show it in a Gtk.TextView, so that I have all the records in one window. At the moment, only the first record is shown in the Gtk.TextView, rather than all of them.

Comment: My guess: It seems that your `records_str` is one long line (I don't see any line break like `\n`). The default behaviour of `Gtk.TextView` is not to wrap the text, so you have all entries but see only the beginning. Try `Gtk.TextView.set_wrap_mode()` or add a line break to each line.

Comment: Excellent, the text wrap has worked so now I can see all of the records. Thanks so much for your help and apologies for my slightly unclear question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written in my comment: Your `for` loop produces one long line without linebreaks, and `Gtk.TextView` does not wrap the line.

From the [Python GTK+ 3 tutorial](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/textview.html):

> Another default setting of the Gtk.TextView widget is long lines of text will continue horizontally until a break is entered. To wrap the text and prevent it going off the edges of the screen call Gtk.TextView.set_wrap_mode().

So you should either add linebreaks to your output string or use the `Gtk.TextView.set_wrap_mode()`.